# single edittext must call textwatcher or act as textview android

Tags: android, textwatcher

Hi in my app there are 2 editText which must display value if the edittext input is from some method and if the input to editText is from keyboard then it must call textwatcher.

that is:

- if the edittext1 has input from virtual keyboard then trigger TextWatcher which will call a method and display value in edittext2[here edittext2 acts as textview]
- if the edittext2 has input from virtual keyboard then trigger textwatcher which will call a method and display result in edittext1[here edittext1 acts as textview]

is this possible? if so please tell me the concepts to follow.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly implementing would probably **CRASH** your app. You can do a work around by using flag variable

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText et1, et2;
    String flag = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        // Here update the flag variable to keep track which text view is in use
        et1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flag = "ET1";
            }
        });

        // Here update the flag variable to keep track which text view is in use
        et2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flag = "ET2";
            }
        });

        et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // Set the value of editText2 value here if only flag contains
                // ET1
                // This will prevent changes if ET2 is being used
                if (flag.equals("ET1")) {
                    et2.setText(s);
                }
            }
        });

        et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // Set the value of editText1 value here only if flag equals ET2
                if (flag.equals("ET2")) {
                    et1.setText(s);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Run** Here double click on a EditText before you type on them. You can further improve this by enabling and disabling the edittext in appropriate situations and hence by doing so you can achieve the same by a single click.

If you have a question about the code, please comment below.

Comment: thanks but cant use checkbox cuz number of keystroke must b reduced... is there a way to detect input to edittext is from virtual keyboard?

Comment: A TextWatcher will help you in that case. And could you explain more about what you mean by `number of keystroke must be reduced`

Comment: in my app there has to be only 5 edittext and no other widgets... can't it be done externally so when the keystroke is from virtual key then call the watcher function else act as textview?

Comment: How about this. Set onClick listener to both the edittext, now depending on which edittext is clicked, set a value to some variable (similar way i used a checkbox), and before setting the values to the edittext check the values of the variable and set accordingly.

Comment: sorry dnt follow can u please explain

Comment: Give me five minutes, I will update my answer which will just use only two edittext and no more widgets. `Code explains more better`